# Is there a surrender option?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

I was in a horrible match where our Commander left and nobody stepped up for a few minutes, and by then the enemy had Flame Turrets in all of our spawns. IS there any way to just forfeit the match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commander can start a surrender vote which the team has to accept by pressing F1 (I think 75% have to accept, not exactly sure).

However, the commander has to be in the bunker (if he gets killed on the way to the bunker every time => no surrender possible) and it only works if a building is missing in the base. For example to unlock surrender early, it is possible to just sell the default MG turret and the button will appear in the top right.

I'm a little unsure about the exact conditions for when the surrender button appears and sometimes it is even gone for good eventhough there are no buildings other than the bunker left and there isn't a surrender vote active.

In my experience, surrender votes never get through thanks to too many players with a "never surrender" mentality even if they die the second they spawn, so hoping on surrender is futile anyways.